# How to add increase /configure weight/boldness (FontWeight) of an Icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, icons

I have an Icon (Back Icon to be Specific) in My Flutter App. It Looks Lighter. I Want to Make It Bold/Increase weight for Some Reason.

```dart
Container(
    child: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        color: Color(0xffffffff),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10.0, 0, 0.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff03b673),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
    ),
)
```

Can't Find Any Thread/Documentation Regarding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

icon `size`

```
Container(
child: Icon(
    Icons.arrow_back,
    color: Color(0xffffffff),
    size: 24.0
 ),
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
 margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10.0, 0, 0.0),
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(0xff03b673),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
 ),
)
```

At the moment,I think there is no `fontWeight` property on icons. you may import custom icon from `fluttericon.com` and when you import it under fonts you can set the font weight like this in pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
 fonts:
 - family: MyIcon
  fonts:
    - asset: lib/fonts/iconfont.ttf
      weight: 400
```

For complete steps follow this nice article: https://developpaper.com/flutter-taste-1-3-step-use-custom-icon/

Comment: But Size and Weight are Two Differen't Things. Isn't it?

Comment: thats right, two different things, at the moment i guess there is no built in property, you may set up your own custom icon from official fluttericon.com and set the font weight to the entire family, see my updated answer above

Comment: Yeah, Importing New Font Did it. I am Using FontAwesome Now :)

Answer (score 19):

Question is old, but I hope it will help someone.

Before:

```
Icon(
  CupertinoIcons.exclamationmark_circle,
  color: Colors.red,
  size: 16.0,
)
```

After (with `FontWeight`):

```
Text(
  String.fromCharCode(CupertinoIcons.exclamationmark_circle.codePoint),
  style: TextStyle(
    inherit: false,
    color: Colors.red,
    fontSize: 16.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    fontFamily: CupertinoIcons.exclamationmark_circle.fontFamily,
    package: CupertinoIcons.exclamationmark_circle.fontPackage,
  ),
)
```

Of course, your icons should support different weights. Icon from my example supports only 2 weights:

1. `thin <= FontWeight.w500`
2. `thick >= FontWeight.w600`

Comment: Thank you for this. I improved an icon's appearance thanks to you. Would be so great if we could freely change to all weights for all icons. Do you know of any resource to find icons/icon packs that have multiple weights?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want to change the **weight of the icon**

Starting from Flutter 3.10.0 and above versions:

Material design 3 is implemented in Flutter so that you can specify the weight of the icon easily like this example:

```
Icon(Icons.star_outline,weight: 10)
```

Comment: In Flutter 3.13.2 changing the weight does not change the icon stroke thickness.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the weight (stroke thickness) [requires the underlying icon font to support the wght FontVariation axis](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Icon/weight.html). I've found that none of the icons provided by default support this property. Therefore, setting the `weight` property does nothing for such icons.

The icons in the [material_symbols_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/material_symbols_icons) package support the weight property. For example:

```
import 'package:material_symbols_icons/symbols.dart';
...
          Icon(Symbols.chevron_right, weight: 100)
```

Answer (score -4):

You can do it by specifying icon size.

```
Container(
    child: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
        size: 20.0,
        color: Color(0xffffffff),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10.0, 0, 0.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff03b673),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
    ),
)
```

Comment: But Size and Weight are Two Differen't Things. Isn't it?