# How to add width to icon without Materialbutton - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, material-ui

I want to display a bold icon in my app, but I don't want to use a material icon since it would display a splash effect when I press on it, and I don't want that. Is there a method to make icons wider in Flutter?

My icon:-
[image]

My desire result:-
[image]

Here is my code:-

```
 Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.add,
                                color: DarkBlueColor,
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: add your code snippet

Comment: you mean increase the size of these icon?

Comment: what about using `size` on icon?

Comment: no I mean I want to increase width of icon like we add width to text

Comment: Do you mean the icon is bold and has a border radius?

Comment: See my answer if the icon is bold and has a border radius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter).

Example code:

```dart
FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use icons inside the text widget and assign font size, font weight, font family and package also this makes your icon bold

```
Text(
  String.fromCharCode(CupertinoIcons.exclamationmark_circle.codePoint),
  style: TextStyle(
    inherit: false,
    color: Colors.red,
    fontSize: 30.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    fontFamily: CupertinoIcons.exclamationmark_circle.fontFamily,
    package: CupertinoIcons.exclamationmark_circle.fontPackage,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can achieve the effect by simply removing the splash/ripple, you can set `ThemeData.splashColor` to transparent.

```dart
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  child: Widget(), // Set your button here
);
```

Otherwise, if what you meant on "width" of the icon is "boldness" or "weight". [Here's a workaround for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57243565/2497859).

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom icon just download the add **' + '** icon online and paste it in your assets folder.

Now use that icon like this --

```
Image.asset('assets/add.png', width: 25, height: 25),
```

Now you can set the width according to your need.

And if you want to get rid of that splash effect just set

```
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
```

Answer (score 1):

simply you can set the splash color to transparent

Comment: no because when I click on button button onto call I want to call parent onto property

Answer (score 0):

You can use, Container and RichText combo. As shown below.

```
 InkWell(
                child: Container(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green,border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.green),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25) ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.indigo,
                        size: 34,
                      ),
                      Text(
                      "Add Offer",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo, fontSize: 20),

                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: (){
                  doSomething();
                },
              ),

 void doSomething() {}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
         InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print("object");
            },
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Material(
                shape: const CircleBorder(),
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 180,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xff59e7ba),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            size: 40,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              "Add Offer",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                //set your fonts
                                //fontFamily: "Font2",
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: you can change you font and color like that.

Answer (score -1):

```
Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 180,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xff59e7ba),
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 40,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    "Add Offer",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ), // Set your button here
      )
```